# For every newly opened terminals, why do I have to source setup.bash and execute catkin_make again?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, raspberrypi, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I' m new to ROS, and running ROS kinetic on a raspberry pi 3B with ubuntu installed.

I have noticed that each time I open up a new terminal, I have to source  /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash and execute catkin_make though I have done so previously in other terminals.

I don' t know whether it is correct to source and catkin_make every time or something has gone wrong. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286466/for-every-newly-opened-terminals,-why-do-i-have-to-source-setup.bash-and-execute-catkin_make-again?/) by [Seagull](https://answers.ros.org/users/33506/seagull/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have noticed that each time I open up a new terminal, I have to `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

yes, that is needed in every terminal (or really: `bash` instance)

> and execute catkin_make

No, that should not be needed.

> why do I have to source and execute catkin_make again?

This question has been posted and answered quite a few times already. See the following for related / duplicate questions: #q124131, #q239131, #q229365, #q188309 and #q200174.

And the following questions try to explain why this is needed: #q241528, #q251292 and #q252715.

In short: `setup.bash` configures your shell so that it can find ROS programs and lets those programs find the required ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seagull](https://answers.ros.org/users/33506/seagull/) on 2018-03-25**:
Thanks. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to avoid having to manually source your workspace you can add the line to your `.bashrc` file.

```
source <path to my workspace>/devel/setup.bash
```

Then this will automatically be executed every time you open a new terminal. As gvdhoorn has said, there is no reason you should have to re-catkin_make your workspace in every terminal. Try adding this line to your `.bashrc` file and let us know if this doesn't solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-25**:
This is explained in the Q&As that I linked. I didn't want to duplicate all of that again.